# android update specific child item expandable listview

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have an expandable listview which has switches in each child view.
I want to change the switch of a specific child.

This is my getChildView function:

```
@Override
    public View getChildView(final int listPosition, final int expandedListPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.node_child, null);
        }

        TextView switchTitleTextView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.switchName);
        switchTitleTextView.setText("Switch " + (expandedListPosition + 1));

        final StickySwitch stickySwitch = (StickySwitch)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.sticky_switch);

        stickySwitch.setOnSelectedChangeListener(new StickySwitch.OnSelectedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedChange(@NotNull StickySwitch.Direction direction, @NotNull String text) {

                if(direction == StickySwitch.Direction.RIGHT) {

                    try {
                        Log.d("Switch RIGHT", "Pressed");


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                if(direction == StickySwitch.Direction.LEFT) {

                    try {
                        Log.d("Switch LEFT", "Pressed");

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
```

Now I have to change the direction of a specific switch. Say group 4 and child 2. I'm not sure how to update specific child and change it's switch to left or right.

Comment: A simple way, you can hold a flag in your dataset and on event you can change that value and fire the notifyDataSetChanged() api

Comment: @Neji yes but how do I change it for a specific child? I have the group number, and I have the child number. How do I change the specific child and let all others remain unchanged?

Comment: hold a flag in the dataset that you use to populate views, set it on the event by getting object using the array and position that you get in callback and fire the notify event

Comment: Oh. I get it. So I call the getChild() in my update function and call notifydatasetchanged() after changing the child's flag, will it work?